# Tighter bounds on eigenvalues than Gershgorin for psd matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have $X$ and $Y$ sample covariance matrices taken from the same probability distribution and finding that diagonal entries of $U^T Y U$ are within a factor of 2 of eigenvalues of $Y$ where $U$ are eigenvectors of $X$.

Meanwhile Gershgorin circle bounds are an order of magnitude higher. Are there different bounds that are more appropriate to use in this situation? IE, getting estimate of eigenvalues of a symmetric p.s.d matrix which has been "almost" diagonalized.